# How do I pass the this context to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I thought this would be something I could easily google, but maybe I'm not asking the right question...

How do I set whatever "this" refers to in a given javascript function?

for example, like with most of jQuery's functions such as:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
   //$(this) gives me access to whatever selector we're on
});
```

How do I write/call my own standalone functions that have an appropriate "this" reference when called?  I use jQuery, so if there's a jQuery-specific way of doing it, that'd be ideal.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520019/controlling-the-value-of-this-in-a-jquery-event/520417#520417

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for others landing here see jQuery `$.proxy`

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Javascripts `.call()` and `.apply()` methods allow you to set the **context** for a function.

```
var myfunc = function(){
    alert(this.name);
};

var obj_a = {
    name:  "FOO"
};

var obj_b = {
    name:  "BAR!!"
};
```

Now you can call:

```
myfunc.call(obj_a);
```

Which would alert `FOO`. The other way around, passing `obj_b` would alert `BAR!!`. The difference between `.call()` and `.apply()` is that `.call()` takes a comma separated list if you're passing arguments to your function and `.apply()` needs an array.

```
myfunc.call(obj_a, 1, 2, 3);
myfunc.apply(obj_a, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Therefore, you can easily write a function `hook` by using the `apply()` method. For instance, we want to add a feature to jQuerys `.css()` method. We can store the original function reference, overwrite the function with custom code and call the stored function.

```
var _css = $.fn.css;
$.fn.css = function(){
   alert('hooked!');
   _css.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Since the magic `arguments` object is an array like object, we can just pass it to `apply()`. That way we guarantee, that all parameters are passed through to the original function.

Comment: Just a fun tidbit: if you need to call the function repeatedly in reference to `obj_a`, for example, you can create a copy of it with `var boud_myfunc = myfunc.bind(obj_a)` and simply call `bound_myfunc()` as needed.

Answer (score 58):

[Use `function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var f = function () { console.log(this); }
f.call(that, arg1, arg2, etc);
```

Where `that` is the object which you want `this` in the function to be.

Comment: `function` is a reserved keyword; consider updating your response to include a named function since `function.call(...)` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @DanielAllen: Without the definition of whatever sample function name I would provide, the code will still throw a JS error. But, I updated the sample function name.

Comment: Works like magic, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 38):

Another basic example:

NOT working:

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
   this.myGlobalFunction(img);
};
img.src = reader.result;
```

Working:

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
   this.myGlobalFunction(img);
}.bind(this);
img.src = reader.result;
```

So basically: just add .bind(this) to your function

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much easier syntax, much easier on the mind...good job Joery

Answer (score 33):

You can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function to set the context of `this` within a function.

```
function myFunc() {
  console.log(this.str)
}
const myContext = {str: "my context"}
const boundFunc = myFunc.bind(myContext);
boundFunc(); // "my context"
```

Comment: I doubt this answer, which is currently the correct answer, will ever get the most votes. There should be an option to view answers where upvotes are weighted based on the time that has passed.

Answer (score 17):

jQuery uses a `.call(...)` method to assign the current node to `this` inside the function you pass as the parameter.

**EDIT:**

Don't be afraid to look inside jQuery's code when you have a doubt, it's all in clear and well documented Javascript.

ie: the answer to this question is around line 574,
 `callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false`