# How can I bind the 'this' context correctly on a prototype.object?

Tags: javascript, scope

The code example:

```
function Test() {
    this.name = 'test'
}

Test.prototype.normal = function() {
    console.log('normal', this.name);
};

Test.prototype.special = {
    name: 'special',
    start: function () {
        console.log("special", this.name);
    }
}

test = new Test;

test.normal(); // Response 'normal, test'

test.special.start(); // Response 'special, special'
```

I'd like the `special.start` function to log 'special, test'

How can i achieve this? I am using coffeescript so a coffee example would be appreciated but a javascript example works just as well! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? And the function's normal `this` is not in any way scoped to the function Test. Nor is `special.start` scoped to a prototype. The `this` value is set dynamically by the JavaScript runtime on every call.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for the info

Comment: `Test.prototype.special.start = Test.prototype.special.start.bind(this);` – Just **no**. You're re-binding the prototype, which affects every single instance. You'll get really confusing results when you add `test2 = new Test` and `test3 = new Test`.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll change it then to the example you provided.

Comment: Still no. You're modifying the `.special` object of the prototype, which is also shared between all instances. You need to do it as I show in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've got the code working correctly now for all instances

Comment: @The person who downvoted. Is the question better now or does it still need editing? Please provide pointers to improve rather than just a simple down-vote click..

Comment: @Dex, your question feels like "I wan this output. How should I change my code?". Where is the learning part in this question? I don't think this question will be helpful to anyone other than yourself.

Comment: @Kira, thanks. How should I rename the question you think? I don't really know the terminology of this problem as was pointed out to me earlier :)

Comment: I hope you learned something new by now. Think what you didn't know at the time of asking this question and change it accordingly

Comment: I think editing this question might make it a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function

Comment: I think it is similar due to the context request but not a duplicate since we tried to pre-bind it instead of assinging it each call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The value of `this` is decided at *call time*, by how the function is called.
2. You want to bind to `test` (the instance), not `Test` (the constructor function).

If you don't want to make specific call-time adjustments but instead pre-bind the function to the `test` instance, that can obviously not happen before you have an instance, and it must happen for each instance individually. Hence the only solution to this is:

```
function Test() {
    this.special = {
        start: (function () { ... }).bind(this)
    };
}
```

Perhaps you'll want to define the function on the prototype instead of inline; but you'll still need to bind it in the constructor:

```
function Test() {
    this.special = {
        start: this._start.bind(this)
    };
}

Test.prototype._start = function () { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about this argument in a function. Try using apply or call methods

```js
test = function(){ this.name = 'test'; }

test.prototype.special = { name:'special', start : function(){alert(this.name)} }

var t = new test();

t.special.start.call(t);

t.special.start();
```

In Javascript, if I call a method like `obj.myMethod` then this keyword inside `myMethod` will refer to the variable `obj`. We can change the value of `this` keyword inside `myMethod` using the functions [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Instead of using call everywhere, we can create a new function with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
test = function(){ this.name = 'test'; }

test.prototype.special = { name:'special', start : function(){alert(this.name)} }

var t = new test();

//t.start and t.special.start are now different functions as per MDN
t.start = t.special.start.bind(t);

t.start();

t.special.start();
```

[Call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Thx Kira! However now I'd constantly need to use call or apply. Can't I pre-bind this?

Comment: @Dex Variables in the `prototype` are shared by all instances. If you bound the function to one instance, then it would ruin the `this` binding for any other instances. Perhaps you shouldn't be using the `prototype`.

Comment: @ZombieChowder It's preferable to have attribution on links where possible.

Comment: there is Function.bind method, instead of calling test.special.start(), you can call like test.start()

Comment: @Kira The `bind` method is what I was saying would break the function for all other instances.

Comment: no, it will not. It will create a new function. We can call it whenever we want or wherever we want

Comment: @4castle, pls check mdn docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: So in the constructor should I add something like: `Test.prototype.special.start.bind(Test);`?

Comment: Ohh i mean: `Test.prototype.special.start.bind(this);` so it's bound to that specific instance?

Comment: no, bind will return a new function, something like Test.prototype.special.start = Test.prototype.special.start.bind(this); will do but I would recommend something like Test.prototype.start = Test.prototype.special.start.bind(Test);

Comment: @Dex no. You can't have it both ways. Either its bound with bind at evaluation time (and would be `undefined` or `window` in your example) or its bound at call time for each instance. Read Deceze's answer.

Comment: @Kira answering the question the OP asked is good. Answering the *real* question (the one implied by the OPs misunderstanding of how `this` works) is better. Its not actually clear what the OP is trying to do here.

Comment: @Jared Smith I think i misunderstood .bind() rather than the this scope or am i wrong?

Comment: @Dex, I explained a little bit about how this works inside a function in answer. Usage of this keyword in JavaScript is not something that I can explain over this answer. You may find the following link useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: unlike apply and call, bind will create a new function instead of calling them directly

Comment: @Dex see my answer

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers already present based on the comments on Kira's answer, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how scoping works. Javascript has lexical scoping, meaning scope is defined by the structure of the source code, with one exception: `this`. `this` is dynamically scoped, meaning that scope is defined by the *caller*. In code:

```
bar = 3
test = (foo) ->
  foo + bar # bar can be seen, because its in an outer scope test can see
```

So far so good. Now lets define a class:

```
class Test
  constructor: (@foo) ->
  getFoo: -> @foo
```

The `getFoo` part is equivalent to `Test.prototype.getFoo = function...`. The `this` (@) is scoped to `getFoo`. The *invoker* of `getFoo` determines the `this`:

```
obj1 = new Test 2
obj1.getFoo() # 2

fn = Test.prototype.getFoo;
fn()
```

`fn` is now a stand alone function instead of a method of `obj1`. When we call `fn` one of two things will happen. If we're in strict mode it will throw an error. Because we're invoking in a global context `this` in `getFoo` is undefined. In non-strict it will be the global `window` and it will look for a foo property that probably isn't there.

We can *force* the `this` value via `bind`, `call`, or `apply`.

```
obj2 =
  foo: 3

Test.prototype.getFoo.call(obj) # 3
```

Here we've used it to 'borrow' a method of the Test class. So where does bind come in? Lets say that our class has a method we *know* will be used in a different context, like an event handler:

```
class Test
  constructor: (@foo) ->
    @clickHandler = Test.prototype.clickHandler.bind this

  clickHandler: (e) ->
    console.log @foo
```

Because we'll be passing the method to `.addEventListener` the `this` context will evaporate, meaning we'll need to bind it to each instance, which we do in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, so what I've writen in the EDIT2  is now valid?

Comment: @Dex its valid, although the cases where you'd actually *do* that are rare. I used the example of an event handler, but `setTimeout` would also be a legit use case. Basically you only do this when using an object method as a higher-order function (a function argument to another function).