# Scoping issue with jQuery UI Widget Factory

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I have a scoping problem that i cannot find a solution for in Google here is a simplified version of my code

```js
jQuery.widget( "myNamespace.myPlugin", {

  options: {},

  _create: function() {
    $main = this.element;
  },
  
  _init: function() {
    $main.text('ajax running');
    $.ajax({url:'some/url/path'})
    .done(function(data) {
      this._callback(data);
    });
  },
  
  _callback: function() {
    
    $main.text('ajax complete');
  }

});

$('.widget_element').myPlugin();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </head>
  <div class="widget_element"></div>
</html>
```

The error i am getting is:

`TypeError: this._callback is not a function`

Is there a better way of performing this task in within the widget environment?

Thanks

Comment: I've posted my current solution, however if you know of a better one please post it and i will accept if valid

Comment: This isn't a jquery-ui specific issue. More solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most problems, a solution only rears its head AFTER you post a question on SO

Aparently `self = this` is perfectly valid

```js
jQuery.widget( "myNamespace.myPlugin", {

  options: {},

  _create: function() {
    self = this;
    $main = this.element;
  },
  
  _init: function() {
    $main.text('ajax running');
    $.ajax({url:'some/url/path'})
    .done(function(data) {
      self._callback(data);
    });
  },
  
  _callback: function() {
    
    $main.text('ajax complete');
  }

});
```

I hope this helps someone in the future