# How do I pass the jQuery selection object into a function being called by the selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to jQuery and I don't know how else to say it.

When the function below is within the jquery selection, it works fine. When I try to break out the function I'm not sure what object/variable needs to be passed into the function in order to make the function work.

```
//function included in selection works great
$('#id1 tbody tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(
function(i,t){
    return Math.round((parseInt(t,10) / 60)*100)/100;
});

//function broken out returns NaN in HTML
$('#id2 tbody tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(minutesToHours());

function minutesToHours(i,t){
    return Math.round((parseInt(t,10) / 60)*100)/100;
}
```

It's the same function but returns 'NaN' in the HTML. I know I need to pass the object into the function `minutesToHours()`, but nothing I've tried works-- `this` or `$(this)`. `minutesToHours('whatGoes','here')`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkuethen/nu6zczu4/)

I'm assuming this has something to do with [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function) but I can't figure it out.

Example HTML

```
<table id="id1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sally</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>610</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>249</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="id2" style="margin-top:1em;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>800</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sally</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>610</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>249</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result

```
Included function
    John    2   13.33   4
    Sally   5   10.17   9
    Bob     7   4.15    3

Broken out function
    John    2   NaN 4
    Sally   5   NaN 9
    Bob     7   NaN 3
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to reference the function `$('#id2 tbody tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(minutesToHours);`

Comment: @adeneo Thanks! Why is that? If I don't pass anything does it assume the context of the selection, like I'm passing `this`?

Comment: Yes, that about sums it up. When you add the parentheses you call the function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further explain Adeno's answer in the comments:

[From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> .text( function )
>
> function
>
> Type: Function( Integer index, **String text** ) => String
>   A function returning the text content to set. *Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.*

This means that when you call the below, `t` is filled with *the old text value*:

```
$('#id1 tbody tr').find('td:eq(2)').text( function(i,t){
    return Math.round((parseInt(t,10) / 60)*100)/100;
});
```

However, when you use `minutesToHours()` in the below, you are actually calling `minutesToHours()` *with no parameters* and passing the returned value into `.text()` Since you didnt pass any variables to the function,`t` is undefined and the function produces `NaN`:

```
$('#id2 tbody tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(minutesToHours());

function minutesToHours(i,t){
    return Math.round((parseInt(t,10) / 60)*100)/100;
}
```

And a different signature for `.text()` is used:

> .text( text )
>
> text
>
> Type: String or Number or Boolean
>   The text to set as the content of each matched element. When Number or Boolean is supplied, it will be converted to a String representation.

With Adeno's suggestion, you drop the `()` from `minutesToHours()` like the below. Now you are passing a reference to the `minutesToHours` function into `.text()` *not calling the function* . When, `.text()` sees the parameter is a function, it will call the function in that context, passing in the two values `(index, text )` and all is right with the world:

```
$('#id2 tbody tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(minutesToHours);

function minutesToHours(i,t){
    return Math.round((parseInt(t,10) / 60)*100)/100;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense to me now. Thanks so much!