# Why does passing a JavaScript object's method not update the object?

Tags: javascript, object, parameter-passing, instance-variables

I noticed that when passing an object's method (which updates one of the object's own properties) as an argument to another function, the original object will not be modified.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: 0,
    bar: function () {
        this.foo++;
    }
};

function baz(callback) {
    callback();
}

baz(obj.bar); // does not alter obj
obj.bar(); // increments obj.foo successfully
console.log(obj.foo); // should be 2, not 1
```

Why is this, since JavaScript objects are passed by reference?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the context - or `this` value - of a function is based on how it's *called*, not on how it's *defined*.  Your `bar` function doesn't know it's inside the `obj` object.

When you do `obj.bar();`, you are calling it *in the context of* `obj`, thus `this` is what you expect.

When you do `baz(obj.bar);`, you are passing the `bar` function as a parameter.  It no longer has any ties to the `obj` object.  Remember, functions can be treated like variables.  So, when `baz` runs its callback, it's ran in the "global" context (`this` is `window`).

The solution here is to use `.bind()` to "lock in" the `this` value.

```
baz(obj.bar.bind(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to bind the callback to a specific object.

```
baz(obj.bar.bind(obj));
```

Functions are only automatically bound to the object before `.` when you perform the call in the same expression. Simply accessing the property doesn't bind it.