# Passing $(this) to a new P5 instance is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

In the code below, I'm looping through each "player_visualizer" element and attempting to create a new P5 instance for each element.

If I `console.log(context)` in the loop I will get the context of that particular element, which is exactly what I need.

```
$('.player_visualizer').each(function (i) {

  context = $(this);

  playerVisualizersP5[i] = new p5(playerVisualizer, context);

});
```

However, The trouble I'm having is **passing the context of that particular element** to the function that will handle all of the P5 animations.

For example, when I try and pass that context variable to the function below and do `console.log(p.context)`, the context variable is always **undefined**.

```
 let playerVisualizer = function (p, context) {

      p.context = context;

 }
```

I've done a fair amount of research on what I could do about this, but I can't seem to tie it back to my particular situation. I've narrowed down my research to a few resources below.

http://hugoware.net/blog/passing-context-with-javascript

[How do I pass the this context to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function)

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you believe that passing something into the `p5` constructor will automatically pass that argument into the `playerVisualizer` function?

From [the P5.js documentation](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode):

> One final note: when creating a p5 instance, you can specify a second
>   argument (HTML element id) which acts the parent for all elements
>   created by the sketch. For example, let's say you have:
>
> ```
> <body>
>   <div id = "p5sketch">
>   </div>
>
>   <p>Some other HTML</p>
> </body>
> ```
>
> You can now say:
>
> ```
> var myp5 = new p5(s,'p5sketch');
> ```
>
> And all elements will be created inside that div.

This means the only valid second argument is a string ID, which gets used by P5.js but isn't passed into the sketch function.

To understand better what's going on, let's look at this example:

```
var s = function( sketch ) {
  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
        sketch.background(128);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

In this example sketch, there are a few things to understand:

- `myp5` is an instance of `p5`, which contains P5.js functions like `setup()` and `draw()` and `background()`.
- `s` is a sketch function, which takes an instance of `p5`.
- `sketch` is an instance of `p5`, which `s` can use to access P5.js functions.

In other words, `myp5` and `sketch` are the same object.

This is useful to you, because if you want to pass data into `sketch`, you can pass that data into `myp5`, like this:

```
var s = function( sketch ) {


  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
        sketch.background(128);
        sketch.text(sketch.extraThing, 20, 20);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
myp5.extraThing = "testing";
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. This is exactly what I needed!