# Set a custom environment to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find a way to set a custom environment to a function in Node.JS.

For example:

```
var context = { // Define env for the function
    foo: function(){
        return "bar"
    },
    test: function(arg){
        doThings(arg);
    }
}

var func = function(){ // Define the function
    test(foo());
}

setCustomEnv(func,context) // Inject the function into the function (and if possible run it)
```

Comment: can you describe what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to find a library or something similar to inject a custom environment to a function, the environment should only work on that function and everything called from it. The function that injects should  at least support 2 args which are the function and the custom env. I hope I've explained well what I meant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass the this context to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function)

Comment: For that you can use mixin..

Answer (score 0):

It would only work if you change `test(foo());` to `this.test(this.foo());`

```
var context = { // Define env for the function
    foo: function(){
        return "bar"
    },
    test: function(arg){
        doThings(arg);
    }
}

var func = function(){ // Define the function
    this.test(this.foo());
}
```

Then you could just write:

```
func.call(context);
```

That way `func` would be called as if it is part of `conext`.