# Can't use setTimeout to undo boolean

Tags: javascript

In my Javascript code I am trying to set up this code

```
    if(this.boolean == true) {
        setTimeout(function(){ this.boolean = false; }, 2000);

    }
```

But for some reason it won't work, the boolean just remains true. How can I fix this/what can I do instead?
The setTimeout works with other lines of code but weirdly not this one.

Comment: The scope of `this` is different within a `setTimeout()`

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630054/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-to-a-function

Comment: you are losing the scope of `this`, try using arrow function:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` behaves in a special way in JavaScript.

Change

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.boolean = false; }, 2000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(() => { this.boolean = false; }, 2000);
```

and the `this` keyword will be interpreted **block-scoped**.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of "this" - you can use a closure to do this:

```
var x = this;
var onTimeout = function(){
  x.boolean = false;
}

if(this.boolean == true) {
       setTimeout(onTimeout, 2000);
}
```

"this" is not what you think it is inside the setTimeout function:

[setTimeout and "this" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript)

If you have ES6 available, arrow functions use their *lexical scope* for `this`

```
var onTimeout = () => this.boolean = false; 
setTimeout(onTimeout , 2000);
```

More about that here:

https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using arrow function, the `this` variable will be the one from `setTimeout` and not your main class because of its [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

The following should resolve the issue.

```
    if(this.boolean == true) {
        setTimeout(() => { this.boolean = false; }, 2000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions have their own `this`, so `this.boolean` inside of function implies that you are trying to change the property boolean of the function itself. On the other hand, if you use arrow functions, you can avoid that because arrow functions don't have their own `this`.

```
setTimeout(() => { this.boolean = false }, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of "this" is changed in your function inside the setTimeout.

You could use the arrow function like other commenters have said.

Or, you can set a var as this, and then use that var in the functions inside the SetTimeout.

```
var coolThis = this;
if(coolThis.boolean == true) {
    setTimeout(function(){ coolThis.boolean = false; }, 2000);
}
```