# How to trigger a function both at click on an element and while landing on a page, preserving $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, function-call

I have a set of Accordion(s) (better say, a set of **expandable sections** in a single page), each of one could be identified by a custom ID (as side note, is a Liferay 7.4 custom fragment).

*I'd need to manage open/close of them not only when their headings are clicked but also in case that in URL is passed an anchor after the friendlyURL.*

I created a specific function that act on each element to manage open/close, and I'd need to trigger it in two cases, obviously on accordion heading click and also comparing the eventual anchor in URL and the corresponding accordion id.

Here a simplified version of my jQuery code, the function is binded at accordion heading click:

```
$('.accordion-heading').on('click',toggleOpen);

function toggleOpen(){
  if( $(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'false' ) {
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded','true');
        $(this).next().removeClass('hide');
    }
    else if( $(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true' ) {
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded','false');
        $(this).next().addClass('hide');
    }
}
```

In this case, `$(this)` selector is perfect for my needs.

---

I tried to add logic to manage also the url anchor auto-open, in the following way:

```
const targetAnchor = $(location).attr('hash');
const thisAnchor = configuration.anchor;   // value taken by fragment configuration is a simple string

if( (targetAnchor.replace('#','')) == thisAnchor) {
    let thisAccordionHeading = $(targetAnchor).find('.accordion-heading');

    console.log($(thisAccordionHeading));  // Verify that target item is correctly found
    
    // ---- execute "toggleOpen" function on this specific item
}
```

In this case, I sincerely don't know how to execute the same function to the `$(thisAccordionHeading)` preserving the logic

Comment: If you just _trigger_ the click event for that element, the `this` context should be correct. `thisAccordionHeading.trigger('click');`

Comment: Effectively in this specific case it seems running correctly (and in this way, I could also avoid to separate actions triggered at click in a dedicated function), but more in general (for other future purposes)... how to execute the function in the second case, avoid to simply trigger a click?

Comment: [How do I pass the this context to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3630054/1427878)

Comment: Agreed with @CBroe

Comment: My preferred method would be to add an extension / *plugin* to jquery - then you can do `$(this).myToggle()` in the handler and `$(thisHead).myToggle()` in the startup.     See [learn.jquery plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) for a starter (also the advanced page after).   Might be a bit overkill for something small.