# Jquery Conversion

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a code snipet where I have handlers like this:

```
_ratingHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRatingChange);
_endClientCallBackHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this.onEndClientCallBack);
```

and I am using them like this:

```
function attachEvent()
 {
    _eventOk = false;
    _eventCallBackOk = false;
    rating1Extender.add_Rated(_ratingHandler);
    rating1Extender.add_EndClientCallback(_endClientCallBackHandler);
}
```

Now I want to conver this code to Jquery. what is the alternative of createDelegate in jquery and how I will modify my attevent function ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Comment: I think you are looking for `.delegate()` or `.live()` on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the Function.createDelegate function in jQuery is the proxy function:

[Similar question on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409920/equivalent-of-asp-net-ajax-function-createdelegate-in-jquery)

[jQuery proxy API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

So it might look something like this:

```
_ratingHandler = $.proxy(this.onRatingChange, this);
_endClientCallBackHandler = $.proxy(this.onEndClientCallBack, this);
```

Or this should work too:

```
_ratingHandler = $.proxy(this, "onRatingChange");
_endClientCallBackHandler = $.proxy(this, "onEndClientCallBack");
```

I don't think you will need to change you attachEvent method but without seeing more of the code it is tough to say.

Comment: @Adam Ayres: I tried both and got undefined when I put alert(ratingHandler ). This is all the related code.

Comment: Could it be that your alert is missing the _: `alert(_ratingHandler)`?  What is the `this` object a reference to, can you show that code?  Where are you applying the event handler?

Comment: this is window. and I am using attachEvent inside a JQuery QUnit Test Like this: module('Attach to onChangeRating');
asyncTest('Attach to onChangeRating', 1, function () {
    rating1Extender = $find('RatingBehavior1');
    attachEvent();
    ok(true, 'testing');
    start();
});

Comment: Does the code extend the window object with the `onRatingChange` function or is the `onRatingChange` function on some other object?  `onRatingChange' is not a native function so somewhere in your code it must be added.  I am familiar with QUnit but you are still not providing enough of the code to troubleshoot the issue.  I suggest you put the code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @Adam: onratingchange is related to ratingControl in ajaxtoolkit here is how it is defined    <aspext:Rating ID="Rating1" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior1" runat="server" CurrentRating="5"
            MaxRating="10" ReadOnly="false" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
            FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" OnChanged="Rating1_Changed"
            Tag="99">
        </aspext:Rating>

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with aspext and this control.