# JQuery event handler scope

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Say I have this (jqueryUI plugin):

```
  $.widget('ui.someplugin', {
    _create: function() {
      return $(this.element).click(this._onClick);
    },
    _onClick: function(e) {
      return this._someFunc();
    },
    _someFunc: function() {
      return console.log('someFunc');
    }
  });
```

It doesn't work - _onClick receives the DOM element as its scope. I could have the handler reference the plugin again with $(e.target).data('someplugin'), but thats then useless if I want to subscribe to other DOM element events. How do I rejig it so that it does what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$.proxy(func, context);`, where `func` will get called with the scope of `context`.

```
return $(this.element).click($.proxy(this._onClick, this));
```

See also: [Controlling the value of 'this' in a jQuery event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520019/controlling-the-value-of-this-in-a-jquery-event)