# Dealing with clash between jQuery and Object's "this"

Tags: jquery, oop

I'm instantiating an Object which creates a DOM element and stores a *jQuery Object* as one of it's properties, e.g.:

```
this.element = $("<div></div>");
```

I noticed that when establishing events, jQuery's rewriting of the`this` context can cause issues, such as if you tried to apply the following:

```
this.element.click(function() {
  this.someObjectMethod();
});
```

The inner `this` now applies to the DOM element and not the original Object. To overcome this, I can do the following:

```
var _this = this;
this.element.click(function() {
  _this.someObjectMethod();
});
```

I'm wondering, is bad practice and is there a better way? I've looked at some [jQuery docs on `apply` and `call`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply) but I'm not sure they'd help in this situation.

Additionally, I'm using [Resig's 'simple inheritence 'Class](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/), which might make a difference to your answers.

**Update** on seeing the `$.proxy` answers, these seem reasonable solutions, however you then lose the ability to reference the DOM element.

Comment: the practice of assigning `this` to another variable is the standard. people generally use `self` or `that` as the name (I prefer `that` as `self` shadows `window.self`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling the value of 'this' in a jQuery event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520019/controlling-the-value-of-this-in-a-jquery-event)

Comment: @jbabey - I've also seen `self` used, though I must admit I find it slightly confusing to use the words interchangably, so I just felt prefixing the `this` might be clearer to me. I like your suggestion of `that` though, might adopt it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
this.element.click($.proxy(function() {
    this.someObjectMethod();
}, this));
```

It returns a function that will always be invoked in the context of the object you specify in the second argument (in our case, the outer `this`).

`$.proxy()` also enforces a special case with event handlers: if you pass the original, unproxied method to `off()` or `unbind()` later, the proxied handler will be transparently removed even though you did not specify it directly.

Comment: Thanks Frederic, though the outcome is very similar, and then I lose the reference to the jQuery element. I wonder if it would even be quicker to just assign a reference to `_this` than to apply the jQuery proxy method.

Comment: @Ian, I don't understand why you lose the reference to the jQuery object. Surely, it is available as `this.element`, since `this` is still your plugin object.

Comment: Good point well made @Frederic, but lets say you had a more complex $(".inside", this.element)

Comment: @Ian, then you'd be better off with an additional `_this` or `that` or `self` variable indeed :)

Comment: This was useful, but I don't like the fact that you lose the reference to the DOM element. I just kept my original code in the end, but I did learn that the `$.proxy` method exists and has some applications :)