# How to bind this to to a jQuery's event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I bind this to a jQuery's event?

For instance, for the [push menu](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas) below, I have to 'remember' `this` to `var root`:

```
class PushMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.slideShown = false;
        var root = this;
        $('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', function() {
            root.slideShown = true;
        });
    }
}
```

But I wonder if I can bind `this` so I can save having `var root`:

```
class PushMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.slideShown = false;
        $('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', function() {
            this.slideShown = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try assigning this to a global variable and binding that variable instead. I am not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using es6 class so i assume es6 syntax are alright with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
$('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', () => {
    this.slideShown = true;
});
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. this is what I am after - ES6! thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery.proxy()`

Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.

```
class PushMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.slideShown = false;
        $('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', jQuery.proxy(function() {
            this.slideShown = true;
        }, this));
    }
}
```

We could have used `jQuery.proxy` here so the reference to this refers to the object of PushMenu instead of the element that triggered the event.

**Documentation**

- [jQuery Proxy Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349380/jquery-proxy-usage)
- [Controlling value of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520019/controlling-the-value-of-this-in-a-jquery-event)